# Save without select

Tags: typeorm, nestjs-typeorm

I used TypeORM in my Nest.js project. Currently, when using the save() method, a select is executed to determine whether an insert or update needs to be carried out.

Instead, is it not possible to check whether an ID is stored in the object and, if so, is an update always carried out? That would mean one less select. If this is possible, where in the TypeOrm source code should I add this?

As an alternative, using insert() and update() is not possible due to listener or save dependencies